# SQL converting rows into columns without pivot

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table named `STUDENTS` with columns `(LNAME, FNAME, PROGRAM)` all `VARCHAR`. Here are the initial results with values added using MS SQL Server 2014:

```
TABLE STUDENTS:

LNAME-------FNAME-------PROGRAM

LEGEND-----MARK--------------IT

SANCHEZ----ERIC---------------IT

RHODES-----JOHN--------------CS

YOUNG-------ART----------------CS

SPARKS------CATH--------------IS

BATUM--------TIM------------------IS
```

I want my table to look like this:

```
IT-----------------------------------------CS-----------------------------------------IS

LEGEND,MARK---------------RHODES,JOHN-----------------------SPARKS,CATH

SANCHEZ,ERIC-----------------YOUNG,ART-----------------------------BATUM,TIM
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can create it manually by using the DataTable in c#.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to approach these problems using conditional aggregation.  The problem is that you don't have a "line number" for sorting.  In SQL Server (and most other databases) you can use `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when program = 'IT' then lname + ',' + fname end) as prog_it,
       max(case when program = 'CS' then lname + ',' + fname end) as prog_cs,
       max(case when program = 'IS' then lname + ',' + fname end) as prog_is       
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by program order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from students s
     ) s
group by seqnum;
```

You can do something similar in MySQL, but it looks quite different.

Comment: +1 Enjoyed your solution... I sqlfiddled it for anyone wanting to play around with it.  Is it just me or has sqlfiddle gotten ridiculously slow ..... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ff8f/7